# Disable scroll offset on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll, offset

I have a little js prob. Here is my code

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 53}, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
```

As you can see I set up an offset of 53px above the target. 53px is the height of my fixed menubar

I'd like to set this offset to 0 on mobile devices as the menubar is hidden.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `window.innerWidth` on this. Usually mobile window is not more than 1024px. On my way of doing this, I'll start with 800px.

Example :

```
if( window.innerWidth > 801 ){
    // offset code to 53 on not mobile
}else{
    // offset code to 0 on mobile
}
```